# Multiple Sqlite3 Joins with Window Function

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables I want to join.

1. Main client table.  I also want to exclude "TERM" records based on FLAG column.
2. BSP table - Match on Client Table, with most recent by date.
3. HRC table - Match on Client Table, with most recent by date.

This should have all non-term clients with the date of most recent BSP and most recent HRC in their own columns.

I am unable to get the third table joined properly.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT *

from 

clients 
left join
( 
  select 
    Hipaa_Short b_h, BSP_Date, 
    row_number() over (PARTITION by Hipaa_Short 
                     ORDER by BSP_Date DESC) 
  as  rn_b
  from BSP
) B

on Clients.Hipaa_Short = B.b_h
where Clients.Status is not "TERM"


;
```

**EDIT**

Changed to this, but not able to only have 1st record from BSP and HRC:

```
SELECT *

from 

clients 
left join
( 
  select 
    Hipaa_Short b_h, BSP_Date, 
    row_number() over (PARTITION by Hipaa_Short 
                     ORDER by BSP_Date DESC) 
  as  rn_b
  from BSP
) B

on Clients.Hipaa_Short = B.b_h

left join
( 
  select 
    Hipaa_Short h_h, HRC_Date, 
    row_number() over (PARTITION by Hipaa_Short 
                     ORDER by HRC_Date DESC) 
  as  rn_h
  from HRC
) H

on Clients.Hipaa_Short = H.h_h

where Clients.Status is not "TERM"
;
```

Table Setup

```
CREATE TABLE Clients (
  "id_pk"   INTEGER,
  Hipaa_Short TEXT,
  Status TEXT, 
  Start_Date TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY("id_pk")
);

INSERT INTO Clients (Hipaa_Short, Status, Start_Date) VALUES 
("Aaliyah", ""          ,"2021-02-01")
,("Aiden",  ""          ,"2020-12-01")
,("Amelia",     "TERM"  ,"2021-08-01")
,("Aria",   ""          ,"2021-07-01")
,("Ava",    ""          ,"2021-06-01")

,("Avery",  ""          ,"2021-03-01")
,("Benjamin",""         ,"2021-10-01")
,("Bob",""              ,"2021-02-01")
,("Caden",  ""          ,"2021-02-01")
,("Camilla",    ""      ,"2021-08-01")

,("Carter", "TERM"      ,"2021-01-01")
,("Charlotte",""        ,"2021-07-01")
,("Eliana", ""          ,"2021-05-01")
,("Elijah", ""          ,"2021-10-01")
,("Emma",   ""          ,"2021-02-01")

,("Ethan",  ""          ,"2020-12-01")
,("Evelyn", ""          ,"2021-03-01")
,("Everly", ""          ,"2021-01-01")
,("Grayson","TERM"      ,"2021-08-01")
,("Isabella",""         ,"2021-07-01")

,("Jackson",""          ,"2021-05-01")
,("James",  ""          ,"2021-07-01")
,("Jayden", ""          ,"2021-07-01")
,("Layla",  ""          ,"2021-01-01")
,("Liam",   ""          ,"2021-01-01")

,("Logan",  ""          ,"2020-03-01")
,("Lucas",  ""          ,"2020-05-01")
,("Luna",   ""          ,"2021-06-01")
,("Mason",  ""          ,"2021-08-01")
,("Mateo",  ""          ,"2021-05-01")

,("Mia",    ""          ,"2020-11-01")
,("Michael",""          ,"2021-10-01")
,("Mila",   ""          ,"2021-05-01")
,("Noah",   ""          ,"2021-07-01")
,("Oliver", ""          ,"2021-01-01")

,("Olivia", ""          ,"2021-01-01")
,("Riley",  ""          ,"2021-08-01")
,("Sebastian",""        ,"2021-02-01")
,("Sophia",""           ,"2021-02-01")
,("Zoe",    ""          ,"2021-05-01")

;


create table BSP (
  "id_pk"   INTEGER,
  Hipaa_Short TEXT,
  BSP_Date TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY("id_pk")
  );
  
 
 INSERT INTO BSP (Hipaa_Short, BSP_Date)
  VALUES
  
("Ava"          ,"2019-11-30")
,("Eliana"      ,"2020-07-31")
,("Ethan"       ,"2020-08-28")
,("Grayson"     ,"2019-12-15")
,("Jackson"     ,"2019-10-20")
,("Jackson"     ,"2020-10-20")
,("Layla"       ,"2019-04-13")
,("Luna"        ,"2019-04-12")
,("Mateo"       , "2020-09-14");
  


create table HRC (
   "id_pk"  INTEGER,
  Hipaa_Short TEXT,
  HRC_Date TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY("id_pk")
  );


INSERT INTO HRC (Hipaa_Short, HRC_Date)
VALUES

("Ava"      ,   "2020-08-21")
,("Eliana"  ,   "2020-07-31")
,("Ethan"   ,   "2019-07-24")
,("Grayson" ,   "2020-02-07")
,("Jackson" ,   "2020-09-14")
,("Layla"   ,   "2019-11-30")
,("Mila"    ,   "2019-01-01");
```

Desired Output

```
| id_pk | Hipaa_Short | Status | Start_Date | b_h     | BSP_Date   | rn_b | HRC_Date |
| ----- | ----------- | ------ | ---------- | ------- | ---------- | ---- | ---------- |
| 1     | Aaliyah     |        | 2021-02-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 2     | Aiden       |        | 2020-12-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 4     | Aria        |        | 2021-07-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 5     | Ava         |        | 2021-06-01 | Ava     | 2019-11-30 | 1    | 2020-08-21 |
| 6     | Avery       |        | 2021-03-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 7     | Benjamin    |        | 2021-10-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 8     | Bob         |        | 2021-02-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 9     | Caden       |        | 2021-02-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 10    | Camilla     |        | 2021-08-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 12    | Charlotte   |        | 2021-07-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 13    | Eliana      |        | 2021-05-01 | Eliana  | 2020-07-31 | 1    | 2020-07-31 |
| 14    | Elijah      |        | 2021-10-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 15    | Emma        |        | 2021-02-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 16    | Ethan       |        | 2020-12-01 | Ethan   | 2020-08-28 | 1    | 2019-07-24 |
| 17    | Evelyn      |        | 2021-03-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 18    | Everly      |        | 2021-01-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 20    | Isabella    |        | 2021-07-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 21    | Jackson     |        | 2021-05-01 | Jackson | 2020-10-20 | 1    |          |
| 22    | James       |        | 2021-07-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 23    | Jayden      |        | 2021-07-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 24    | Layla       |        | 2021-01-01 | Layla   | 2019-04-13 | 1    | 2019-11-30 |
| 25    | Liam        |        | 2021-01-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 26    | Logan       |        | 2020-03-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 27    | Lucas       |        | 2020-05-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 28    | Luna        |        | 2021-06-01 | Luna    | 2019-04-12 | 1    |          |
| 29    | Mason       |        | 2021-08-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 30    | Mateo       |        | 2021-05-01 | Mateo   | 2020-09-14 | 1    |          |
| 31    | Mia         |        | 2020-11-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 32    | Michael     |        | 2021-10-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 33    | Mila        |        | 2021-05-01 |         |            |      | 2019-01-01 |
| 34    | Noah        |        | 2021-07-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 35    | Oliver      |        | 2021-01-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 36    | Olivia      |        | 2021-01-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 37    | Riley       |        | 2021-08-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 38    | Sebastian   |        | 2021-02-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 39    | Sophia      |        | 2021-02-01 |         |            |      |          |
| 40    | Zoe         |        | 2021-05-01 |         |            |      |          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQJv5HTj5vsApmPEUBR2n/4)

```
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aQJv5HTj5vsApmPEUBR2n/4
```

Comment: *I am unable to get the third table joined properly.* ... why? Simply add another `LEFT JOIN` for the `HRC` table exactly like you did `BSP`. Please give it a try and come back with specific issues.

Comment: Was able to join the HRC table, changed Q to reflect it.  But I don't understand how to just have the newest record in BSP and HRC.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add each calculated  `ROW_NUMBER` to `ON` clause equal to 1:

```sql
SELECT c.id_pk, c.Hipaa_Short, c.Status, c.Start_Date,
       B.b_h, B.BSP_Date, H.h_h, H.HRC_Date
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT
       Hipaa_Short AS b_h
       , BSP_Date
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by Hipaa_Short 
                            ORDER by BSP_Date DESC) AS rn_b
    FROM BSP
   ) B
  ON c.Hipaa_Short = B.b_h
  AND B.rn_b = 1                     -- ADDED CONDITION
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT
       Hipaa_Short AS h_h
       , HRC_Date
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by Hipaa_Short 
                            ORDER by HRC_Date DESC) AS rn_h
    FROM HRC
   ) H
ON c.Hipaa_Short = H.h_h
AND H.rn_h = 1                       -- ADDED CONDITION
WHERE c.Status IS NOT 'TERM';
```